# Canon SDK for image transfer from DSLR to iPhone or iPad

Tags: ios, sdk, edsdk

From the Canon SDK documentation:

EDSDK stands for EOS Digital Camera Software Development Kit. EDSDK provides the functions required to control cameras connected to a host PC, digital images created in digital cameras, and images downloaded to the PC.

I am searching for some SDK or an example project to do anything similar for iOS. Currently this SDK which is written in Objective-C is a 32-bit framework built for Windows or MacOS. I want to build an iOS app for iPhone/iPad that hast at least similar functions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Unfortunately, questions asking for help locating a library/tutorial are considered off-topic. Don’t worry though - once you get going, we will gladly help you if you encounter any problems with your code. As to the matter at hand, you may have best chance finding what you want by contactin Canon technical support directly.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do this.  You can use the camera connection adapter from Apple to read images from a camera file system, but iOS doesn't expose the low-level USB interface you would need to actually control the camera.  You would need to develop such an interface under the MFi program.  You would probably find it easier to support Canon's newer, WiFi enabled cameras as then you don't need a physical connection.